# lookup value associate with list items

Tags: awk

I am trying to approximate vlookup from excel.

I have two files.

file #1 - list.txt:

```
green
purple
orange
```

file #2 - reads.txt:

```
blue 2
green 3
red 5
purple 6
```

I am trying to read in the entries of list.txt, then go to reads.txt and pull out the associated value.

the desired output would be:

```
green 3
purple 6
orange 0
```

if I write:

```
awk -F ' ' 'FNR == NR {keys[$1]; next} {if ($1 in keys) print $1,$2}' list.txt reads.txt
```

I get:

```
green 3
purple 6
```

but nothing for orange, and I need the line:

```
orange 0
```

If I write

```
awk -F ' ' 'FNR == NR {keys[$1]; next} {if ($1 in keys) print $1,$2; else print $1,0}' list.txt reads.txt
```

I get:

```
blue 0
green 3
red 0
purple 6
```

any ideas how to fix this?

major newbie here, so any help appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{map[$1]=$2; next} {print $1, map[$1]+0}' reads.txt list.txt
green 3
purple 6
orange 0
```

Answer (score 2):

***1st solution(with as per shown samples):*** Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  arr[$1]=$2
  next
}
($0 in arr){
  print $0,arr[$0]
  next
}
{
  print $0,0
}
' reads.txt list.txt
```

Output will be as follows, for shown samples.

```
green 3
purple 6
orange 0
```

---

---

***2nd solution(Generic solution):*** In case your Input_file named `reads.txt` has multiple values of same first column and you want to print all values which are present in `list.txt` then please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  ++arr[$1]
  val[$1 OFS arr[$1]]=$2
  next
}
($0 in arr){
  for(i=1;i<=arr[$0];i++){
    print $0,val[$0 OFS i]
  }
  next
}
{
  print $0,0
}
' reads.txt list.txt
```

Sample of run: Let's say your sample of `reads.txt` is this:

```
cat reads.txt
blue 2
green 3
red 5
purple 6
green 15
green 120
```

Now after running this Generic solution we will get following.

```
green 3
green 15
green 120
purple 6
orange 0
```

Comment: these both work well - the generic solution may be useful later - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If order doesn't matter, I'd use a left [`join`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/join.1.html) instead of `awk`:

```sh
$ join -a1 -e 0 -o 0,2.2 <(sort list1.txt) <(sort reads.txt)
green 3
orange 0
purple 6
```

(Assumes a shell like `bash` that supports `<()` command redirection syntax).

Comment: order doesn't matter as long as it is always the same, so useful and thank you!